# Getting invalid argument error when trying to build dockerfile

Tags: docker

```
docker build -t serendipity111011/repo-name:latest -t serendipity111011/repo-name:$SHA -f ./Apollo API/Dockerfile ./Apollo API
```

I am trying to run the above command to build docker image and I am getting below error

```
invalid argument "serendipity111011/repo-name:" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It was actually due to stupidity on my part. You have to escape the space correctly when you write out build commands like below

```
docker build -t serendipity111011/repo-name:latest -t serendipity111011/repo-name:$SHA -f ./Apollo\ API/Dockerfile ./Apollo\ API
```

I hope it helps someone who might be having same issue.